# Request.Files Collection empty when passing from jQuery to ASP.NET code

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am running ASP.NET MVC Beta. I have an AJAX call running through jQuery which grabs my form values and posts them to a controller action. If I run this call without AJAX in a normal form post scenario, everything comes through correctly. However, once I incorporate the jQuery code, all the form values EXCEPT the files come through. Request.Files() returns nothing. Is there an additional piece I am missing here?

HTML code:

```
<form action="/Images/AddImages/" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmAddImages" method="post">
    <%=Html.Hidden("hfPromoId",ViewData.Model.Promotion.PromoId) %>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Images for Promo: </td>
            <td><span class="promoTitle"><%=Html.Encode(ViewData.Model.Promotion.PromoName) %></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="newImageContainer">
            <td>Select Image:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" id="txtImagePath" name="txtImagePath" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="newImageContainer">
            <td>Image Caption:</td>
            <td>
                <input id="txtImageCaption" name="txtImageCaption" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Save Image" id="AddImages" /></td>     
        </tr>
    </table> 
</form>
```

Controller code:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult AddImages(bool? partial)
{
    int promoId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["hfPromoId"]);
    var promo = _promoRepository.GetPromotion(promoId);

    string imageCaption = Request.Form["txtImageCaption"].ToString();
    string imagePath = string.Empty;

    foreach (string file in Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;

        if (hpf.ContentLength == 0)
        { continue; }

        imagePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Content\PromoImages",
                                            promo.PromoId.ToString() + "__" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
        hpf.SaveAs(imagePath);
    }

    _promoRepository.SaveImageForPromo(promoId, imageCaption, imagePath, this.Request);

    if (partial == true)
    {
        return List(true, promoId);
    }

    return View("Images", GetModel(promoId));
}
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#frmAddImages').submit(function() {
            runAjax(form, updateImageList, 'html');
            return false;
        });
});


function runAjax(form, callback, format) {
    $.ajax({
        url: form.action + '?partial=true',
        type: form.method,
        dataType: format,
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        success: callback
    });
}

function updateImageList(result) {
    $('#gallery').html(result);
    setElementStyling();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea,  that makes sense,  jquery serialize isn't going to process file upload data.  You're going to want to look at some sort of plugin to handle the fileupload.  I did some google searching for it and only turned up plugins that allowed styling of the browse button. you may have to take an iframes or silverlight route.

**Update**
As noted in the comment their is a [jQuery Form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) that supports file upload.

Comment: Some of this stuff is still new to me. I used the jQuery Form plugin to achieve the results I needed. Thanks!